# ActionView::Template::Error (formtastic.css isn't precompiled):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, formtastic

Im a newbie to rails and im trying to set my app up on my host provider. However i have run into a problem. My webhost setup is passenger, rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.8.7.  Im having the following issue

```
ActionView::Template::Error (formtastic.css isn't precompiled):

    5:     <title>  <%=h  @club.title %> </title>
    6:   <% end %>
    7: 
    8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", 'formtastic.css','my_formtastic_changes'  %>
    9:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    10:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    11: 
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1734619706_23763401823460'
  app/controllers/news_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

I have precompiled my app using following command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

No joy.

I have tried adding it to my production.rb

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w( formtastic.css )
```

No joy.

My application.css looks like so

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require formtastic
*= require my_formtastic_changes
*/
```

Ive tried with the above and also without the above etc etc

My manifest looks like so

cat manifest.yml

---

```
formtastic.css: formtastic-1c695b81053b6c3b5375b0ceea61290c.css <br>
rails.png: rails-be8732dac73d845ac5b142c8fb5f9fb0.png<br>
application.css: application-58c08b7046a2045ea1395b196ce3607a.css<br>
application.js: application-d1fbc53f1635b41e40f5ebb9a3b000ee.js<br>
```

Ive run into a dead end with trying to get this to work and it is probably something very simple.

Anyone got any ideas? Ive read already a few posts on this but none seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Formtastic README in the section about stylesheet usage in rails > 3.1](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#stylesheet-usage-in-rails--31-1), it looks like the only thing you need to do is add `*= require formtastic` in your application.css-- you don't need to reference `formtastic.css` in your `stylesheet_link_tag` or in your `config.assets.precompile`. It's likely going to be the same thing with your `my_formtastic_changes` stylesheet, so the only thing in the `stylesheet_link_tag` would be `'application'`.

As a side note, both the versions of Ruby and Rails that you're using are old. In particular, Rails 3.2.2 has some security vulnerabilities that were fixed in later versions ([here's one example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/DCNTNp_qjFM)). The most current released version of Rails as of today is 3.2.14, and I would recommend either Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0.0. I realize this might be your host's decision and not yours, and you'd likely be fine with a hobby project, but I would be negligent if I didn't warn you against making a critical production application with these versions.